# mod_rewrite Problem with rewriting optional query from FORM

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

```
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?orderby=([^/.]+)&sort=([^/.]+)$ index.php?category=$1&orderby=$2&sort=$3 [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
```

my html code is like this

```
    <form method="get" action="">....
```

If I submit the form the URL is like this: http://site.com/category?orderby=hits&sort=desc  (The variables orderby and sort dont work)
It looks like my first rule is ignored.

Comment: Welcome to SO. What exactly didn't work where? Can you clarify?

Comment: He ignores the the variables orderby and sort.

Comment: If I submit the form the URL is like this: http://site.com/category?orderby=hits&sort=desc  (The variables orderby and sort dont work)

Comment: You don't need to do any rewrite for the get parameters. You just access them with `$_GET['orderby']` and `$_GET['sort']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `[QSA]` flag (means `query string append`)

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ index.php?category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

`RewriteRule` does not use query string to match url